# Access to property of Bottom Navigation in other Activities

Tags: android, methods, properties, bottomnavigationview

I am a beginner in Android Programming,
 I have defined a Bottom Navigation in my mainActivity and want to access the property and methods of it in other activities(regardless of access in my mainActivity).
is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible . please search through stackoverflow about how to access it

Comment: create a base activity with the bottom navigation, and extend that to othre activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

umm , why dont use fragments instead of activity ? you can sync activity and fragments easily with callback inteface and inside fragments access method in mainActivity .

Comment: So, if I want to use them in fragments, again, how can we access these methods and properties in Fragment?

Comment: @Amir Em use interface for it , see this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)